# Two Lan Ports Into One

Tags: router, lan, combine

So my question is, I have a verzion fios router with 4gb lan ports and have one lan going out to my wan on my Netgear X10 router. I want to take two lan ports to one wan on my router. Can I do this and would it increase my speed to the Netgear router?

Thank you all for your help on this.

Comment: So you believe that by doubling the ethernet connections that will double your speed? That ain’t how it works.

Comment: It's not clear what it is you hope to gain. You say "would it increase my speed to the Netgear router" but why would that matter to you? Do you have any reason to think it matter how fast things get to the router? And do you mean from the Internet? Or from your local network? It's very hard to understand what exactly you're asking.

Comment: Will not increase speed.

Answer (score -2):

The short, technically dlightly incorrect answer is you cant do this.

The long answer is -

You cant take 1 gigabit port and connect it to 2 gigabit ports and get high speed - in fact the best you would get is 100 megabits on 1 of the 2 ports.

You have not stated the speed.of your Internet connection but unless you are purchasing > gigabit from your ISP - which is vanishingly unlikely, increasing the speed between your vios router and x10 wont help because thats not the bottleneck.

I dont know what VIOS hardware is, but if you are truly getting > gig speeds, you could theoretically turn 1 of your X10 ethernet ports into a WAN port and then have 2 wan connections. This is *very hard* to set up and will come with lots of limitations unless the VIOS box does link aggregation, in which case its just very hard.

If your connection is not performing as well as it shoiuld be you should focus on finding and fixing the bottleneck, whivh is unlikrly to be between the VIOS and X10 box unless you have a faulty ethernet cable.

Comment: While the answer is well intentioned, the question is vague and reeks of someone attempting to squeeze proverbial blood from a stone. This is not the kind of question that should be encouraged by an answer.